# Convergence of an Alternating Series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

For this question, I`m trying to determine the values of $p$ in which the series converges.
The series is: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n^p}$.

I already know (by looking at the answer to the question) that the answer is $p>0$. 
However, I'm not sure how to get this answer.
I understand p-series and how $\frac{1}{n^p}$ must have $p>1$. 
But I'm confused about alternating series.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Leibniz Test...

Answer (score 2):

See this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test

Here $a_n=\frac 1{n^p}$ which for $p>0$ are monotonically decreasing and converging to $0$.

Answer (score 1):

- For $p>0$ the sequence $\left(\frac1{n^p}\right)$ is decreasing to $0$ hence using the Leibniz theorem the given series is convergent.
- For $p\le0$ the sequence $\left(\frac{(-1)^n}{n^p}\right)$ doesn't converge to $0$ so the series is divergent
- Conclude.

Answer (score 0):

An alternating series $\sum_n{(-1)^nf(n)}$ converges to a sum $f(0)<S<f(1)-f(0)$ if $f(n)$ is positive and strictly decreasing to zero, for $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

This is because $S_{2n+1}-S_{2n-1}\ge{0}$ and $S_{2n}-S_{2n-2}\le{0}$, implying that $\{S_{2n-1}\}$ (i.e. the odd partial sums) increases and $\{S_{2n}\}$ (i.e. the even partial sums) decreases, for $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Now, $\lim_{n\rightarrow{\infty}}(S_{2n+1}-S_{2n})=\lim_{n\rightarrow{\infty}}(-1)^nf(2n+1)=0$, because $f(n)$ decreases to zero. Therefore, both sequences of partial sums must tend towards the same limit, $S$, which must also fall between $S_0$ and $S_1$.

Now, as long as $p>0$ in the series you provided, the general term, $\frac{1}{n^p}$, tends to zero monotonically, so the theorem applies and the series converges conditionally.